# What is the need for antMatcher("/**") in http.antMatcher("/**") .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm learnig spring security and I came across this piece of code   from https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .antMatcher("/**")
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
        .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
  }
```

I removed `.antMatcher("/**")` and the code is  still working.
I understand `**` matches zero or more directories in a path, So I thought `antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequestes().antMatcher("/login")` would  match `"/login"` that is directly or indirectly under root path, ie I expected it match paths like `/login` and `/demo/login` but that's not the case, It matches only `/login` that's directly underneath the root path.
So what exactly is the need for `.antMatcher("/**") here`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are difference things.

- `http.antMatcher()` configures which URL will be handled by this `SecurityFilterChain`. The default is to match all URL. That why it is the same if you remove `http.antMatcher("/**")`.
- `http.authorizeRequests()` configures the authorisation matter for an URL such as things like if it requires to be authenticated or if only certain roles can access it etc.

So if an URL does not matched with `http.antMatcher()` , Spring security will not handle it and `http.authorizeRequests()` will not apply to this URL. In other words , in order to have the URL configured in `http.authorizeRequests()` to take effect , it should be handled by Spring Security and matched in `http.antMatcher()` too.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the first one is singular `antMatcher` and the second one is plural `antMatchers`, and that the example has them indented differently.

Actually, the example in the question is incorrectly indented. Correct indentation is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .antMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
        .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
}
```

That is because they apply to two entirely different objects:

- The first call applies to the `HttpSecurity` object, and specifies a **master** filter, that is applied before even considering security.

  The default master filter is the [`AnyRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AnyRequestMatcher.html), and the javadoc says:

  > Matches any supplied request.

  When you call `antMatcher("/**")`, you *replace* that filter with an [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) using pattern `/**`, and the javadoc says:

  > Using a pattern value of `/**` or `**` is treated as a universal match, which will match any request.

  As you can see, calling `antMatcher("/**")` has no effect, other than explicitly documenting that security is applied to all requests.
- The second call applies to an `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` object, and specifies an "ant"-filtered "**rule**". There can be many rules defined, e.g. in the example `antMatchers(...)` and `anyRequest()` each start a new rule, and you can have multiple `antMatchers(...)` rules with different patterns.

  Rules are checked in order, until one matches the incoming request.

The master filter and the rule filter must **independently match the request**, in order for the request to be secured, as specified by the rule, e.g. `permitAll()`, `denyAll()`, `authenticated()`, `hasRole("ROLE_FOO")`, etc.