# Spring security what happens If I use antMatches() on http object without authorizeRequests()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to figure out how configure method works in Spring security. And found out that I can call  antMatches() method right on http object without authorizeRequests() like this.

```
   @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher()
               
    // some code
    }
```

As far as I understand authorizeRequests() tells spring that next lines will be restriction of users bases on roles/authorities.

What is the point of calling antMatcher right on http?

Comment: does this help:[http.antMatcher()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484889/what-is-the-need-for-antmatcher-in-http-antmatcher-authorizereque)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the need for antMatcher("/\*\*") in http.antMatcher("/\*\*") .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484889/what-is-the-need-for-antmatcher-in-http-antmatcher-authorizereque)